# pandas.read_csv y-axis contains whole data rows and sklearn.linear model ValueError

Tags: python

I am very new to Python. I inserted a csv-file which contains data about used cars (price, yearOfRegistration, powerPS, Kilometer, model, fuelType) and used a scatter-plot to visualize my data. The x-axis should be the Kilometers and the y-axis the price. After running my code the label of the x-axis looks okay (labels are 20000, 40000, 60000, etc.) whereas the label of the y-axis does not. The label of the y-axis contains whole data rows and one line looks like this: 4500,1999,150,125000,3er,benzin,"BMW...".

I have tried to relabel the y-axis but I think that the problem exists in the csv data?

That is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("./autos_prepared.csv")
#print(df)

print(df.head())

print(df["price"])


from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(df["kilometer"], df["price"])
plt.show()
```

I expected a plot with the x-axis I described above and labels on the y-axis from 0, 10000, 20000, 30000, 40000. Instead I have got the results I described above.

Additionally I would like to add that I have got the

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

after trying to run this code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(df[["kilometer"]], df[["price"]])
#
print("Intercept: " + str(model.intercept_))
print("Coef: " + str(model.coef_))
```

Is there anyone who could help me? That would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I think there indeed was an error in the data. Problem is solved now. I do not know exactly what was wrong but it works now.